# best method for searching php inside html

Tags: javascript, php, html, text, highlight

I have an html that is produced from a txt file using php. I was wondering what the best way to go about building a search feature for this website. I was thinking of Javascript, but for some reason, it doesn't work if the HTML is inside the PHP. It works perfectly on a standalone html file on my local machine. Would PHP be better for this situation?

Here is a sample of the code, so you know what I mean:

```
$fp=fopen("csv/inventory4.html",'w');
$write=fputs($fp,$html_body,strlen($html_body));
$i=0;
$content = file("webinvt.txt");
foreach($content as $line)
{
$l=csv_split($line); etc...
```

There is also another part of the php with html inside

```
  $html_body = '<html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
  <title>CSV Contents</title> etc...
```

etc...

Comment: By search feature, what kind of search feature you want? To search inside of those HTMLs that you load in php ?

Comment: Yes that's it exactly. I would like a simple highlight feature that does or does not include a find button.

Comment: So you want feature like CTRL+F in chrome?

Comment: basically yes. We have customers that don't even know where CTRL is on  the keyboard. This is what we tell them: Press CTRL F. That's horrible and shouldn't be on any live website! eventually I would like to add more features to the search.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I got your question. If I understand you, you have pages and texts in HTML documents, and you load them and display as PHP files. And you wanna build search for those texts.

1st you will need to add search form to your HTML pages. Something like:

```
<form action="" method="get">
Search: <input type="textfield" id="search" name="search" value="search">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

This will make query link from entered criteria, so new link will look like index.php?search=textFromInput.

Then in PHP you process it like this:

```
$criteria = $_GET['search'];
```

After that you have variable $criteria containing user input in search field.
Now when you load file with $fp = fopen("file","r");

User PHP [substring();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to find that criteria in that loaded file.

EDIT:

Try this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="find();">Find in This Page...</a>
```

Comment: OK. I'll play with your suggestions and let you know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, searching of content (*not searching dynamically of a value or something within a single page, then you can certainly use js*) should take place wherever your content resides. In your case the content is at the server so searching should be implemented with a server side technology, at the server side. For your situation using PHP is the best solution.

Comment: thanks for clearing that up. Can you point me to the methodology of implanting a search feature that can highlight the words inside the table with contents of the txt file?